# Haskell "h1>" Syntax and Scientific Unit Checking

Tags: haskell

I've been trying to replicate [this (rather old) tutorial](https://liftm.wordpress.com/2007/06/03/scientificdimension-type-arithmetic-and-physical-units-in-haskell/) on using Haskell's type checker as a unit checker for any arithmetic/maths to have consistent units (i.e. meters, kilograms, seconds and derivatives thereof).

Essentially a way to count Peano numerals is introduced as well as a way to recursively define lists. Then these two features are used to define unit types as lists with each element being a Peano numeral corresponding to what exponent belongs to each of meters, kilograms and seconds.

I am stuck on the following bit of code that they've provided:

```
-- multiply units composed of non-empty lists recursively
instance (Add i j k, Mult r s t) =>
         Mult ((a, i) `Cons` r) ((a, j) `Cons` s) ((a, k) `Cons` t) where
  mult ((a, i) `Cons` r) ((_, j) `Cons` s) h1>
    (a, add i j) `Cons` mult r s
```

Nowhere in the tutorial do I see `h1>` defined. The compiler reports:

```
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
    |
314 |     main :: IO ()
    |     ^
```

Where 314 is the next line of code that worked before introducing the multiplication `instance` definition block. I have tried the following permutation of the above code:

```
-- multiply units composed of non-empty lists recursively
instance (Add i j k, Mult r s t) =>
         Mult ((a, i) `Cons` r) ((a, j) `Cons` s) ((a, k) `Cons` t) where
  mult ((a, i) `Cons` r) ((_, j) `Cons` s) ((a, add i j) `Cons` mult r s)
```

To attain the same result. Since no one complained in the tutorial comments, at the moment I'm guessing that the two option declarations are the culprits:

```
{-# OPTIONS -fglasgow-exts #-}
{-# OPTIONS -fallow-undecidable-instances #-}
```

Since both raise deprecation warnings. But in my mind if something is deprecated, it should still work so am a bit stumped. I am using GHC 8.4.3.

What would be the correct form for the above `instance` declaration?

Comment: (Community: I was tempted to vote-close this as "off topic - small typo", but ended up answering it anyway. I'm not sure what the proper action here should have been, since it's not a typo by the OP, and the OP looked genuinely puzzled by a seemingly strange syntax. Feel free to disagree :-) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that's only a typo, or some HTML which somehow was pasted inside an Haskell script.

The code should likely read as:

```
-- multiply units composed of non-empty lists recursively
instance (Add i j k, Mult r s t) =>
         Mult ((a, i) `Cons` r) ((a, j) `Cons` s) ((a, k) `Cons` t) where
   mult ((a, i) `Cons` r) ((_, j) `Cons` s) = (a, add i j) `Cons` mult r s
```

In the linked tutorial another `h1>` appears, and it should be `=` as well. Even if the tutorial is old, it should compile with a few extensions on. GHC should point out in the error messages which extensions you need. I'd keep recompiling this and enabling extensions as needed.

There's no special `h1>` syntax in Haskell.